# Extracting lines containing a word in a specified field of text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm having some problems extracting data from a file text, I'm gonna show you an example.

This is how the text file is formatted:

```
John England A
Kyle Canada P 
Ash France P
Alex Italy C
Simon Germany C
Thomas Netherlands P
```

Now what I need to do is, after sorting them by alphabetical order on field 1, then selecting only the ones which have a specific third field like P, and put them into another .txt file.

This would be the correct output of the new file:

```
Ash
Kyle
Thomas
```

as you can see, they are sorted by alphabetical order and only the ones with third field value as P are put into the new file.

This is what I've come to:

```
cut -d ' ' -f1 file1.txt | sort
```

which basically just selects the first field and sort it by alphabetical order, what I just can't solve is what to do to now select only the ones having P as third field value (without changing the order just created).

Thanks to anyone who will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '$3=="P"{print $1}' file1.txt | sort > file2.txt
```

Or with `grep`:

```
grep ' P$' file1.txt | sort
```

Comment: @THZ why can't you use awk? It's just a standard tool like cut and sort

Comment: Basically, this is homework, and we never used awk so I'm not supposed to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one with `grep`'n'`cut`'n'`sort` that checks if the line ends in a `P`:

```
$ grep "P$" file | cut -d \  -f 1 | sort
Ash
Kyle
Thomas
```

If you want the `P` in the 3rd field, use:

```
$ grep "^[^ ]\+ [^ ]\+ P$" file | cut -d \ -f 1 | sort
```

Comment: Ok this seems to work, but is the grep command always refering to the 3rd field? What if I had like " Ash P"? Wouldn't it get that too?

Comment: It's referring to the end of the line (`$`). If it needs to be the _3rd field_: `grep "^[^ ]\+ [^ ]\+ P" file | cut -d \  -f 1 | sort`

Comment: Oh right, but then if I had the 3rd field as 2nd field that solution won't work.